# How to transfer duplicates document from one collection to another in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am finding duplicates document using aggregation and then I want to move 
these duplicate documents into another collection. But I don't know how 
to do . I have tried many way but not able to do it in mongodb.

```
outCursor = db.Working_newFooditem.find({}).toArray()
var length = outCursor.length
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
inCursor = db.Working_newFooditem.find({}).toArray()
while (j<=length) {
        var outUniqueString = outCursor[j].uniqueName;
        while (i<= length) {
            var inUniqueString = inCursor[i].uniqueName;
            if(inUniqueString === outUniqueString){
                db.dupC.insert(inCursor[i])
                db.Working_newFooditem.remove(inCursor[i]._id)
            }i++
    }j++
}
```

I have duplicates documents so i made uniqueName field by concatenating other fields of documents, but this uniqueName may repeat two three times because of same documents exists in the collection, so I am  trying to find documents with repeated uniqueName and then want to keep one document in testTemp collection and other duplicate document in abc collection.

Comment: can you show us what you have tried ?

Comment: can you also post the schema? what is duplicate? what are you trying to remove from the document?

Comment: i have uploaded code also can you suggest me how should i proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here goes the possible solution

```
db.Working_newFooditem.find({}).toArray((err, outCursor) => {
  db.Working_newFooditem.find({}).toArray((err, inCursor) => {
    var length = outCursor.length
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (j<=length) {
            var outUniqueString = outCursor[j].uniqueName;
            while (i<= length) {
                var inUniqueString = inCursor[i].uniqueName;
                if(inUniqueString === outUniqueString){
                    db.dupC.insert(inCursor[i])
                    db.Working_newFooditem.remove(inCursor[i]._id)
                }i++
        }j++
    }
  })
})
```

To get data - you should implement callback function for each find query, also you should make them nested.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that your code have mongoDB operations but you have no callbacks nor promises, that's wrong

But assuming that those operations returns `Promises` you could change your code for something like this.

> Using ES2017 `async/await` syntax

```
async function foo() {
    var outCursor = await db.Working_newFooditem.find({}).toArray()
    var inCursor = await db.Working_newFooditem.find({}).toArray()

    for (var out_c of outCursor) {
        var outUniqueString = out_c.uniqueName
        for (var in_c of inCursor) {
            var inUniqueString = in_c.uniqueName
            if (in_c === out_c) {
                await db.dupC.insert(in_c)
                await db.Working_newFooditem.remove(in_c._id)
            }
        }
    }
    return 'good job'
}

foo()
.then(msg => console.log(msg))
.catch(e => console.log(e))
```